# LARAVEL ¿Definir una funcion si se cumple una condición en un objeto?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

¿Hay alguna forma de poder hacer esto dentro de un modelo?
Pongo el ejemplo mal hecho para que se entienda....

```
class MODELO extends Model{
   ...
   if(CONDICION){
      public function RELACION(){
           ...
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Obviamente así no. Claramente estás ante un caso de herencia. Si tienes una Clase y necesitas otra que implemente un método adicional (por lo que planteas) entonces deberías extender de la Clase original y añadir ese método en la Clase extendida. O al menos es lo que entiendo con tu pregunta.

Comment: Si y no... Básicamente, lo que quiero hacer en caso de que una tabla (con la cual esta relacionada) existe, entonces declare dicha función, para no declarar una función sin sentido alguno... (El ejemplo se que no es funcional, es meramente la forma mas visual para ver lo que pretendo hacer)

Comment: No es posible, crea el método y ejecútalo solo si se cumple la condición. En todo caso, declara una variable para determinar si existe la tabla relacionada.

Comment: Es posible de hacer si, utilizando `__call` por ejemplo. Lo que no entiendo es en qué casos puede no existir la relación, si editen la tablas existirá la relación. Si generas tablas dinámicas posiblemente debas revisar tu EER.